# GitHub push with token strangeness

Tags: visual-studio-code, github

I have been trying to push files from a windows 10 laptop to a repo in my GitHub account. I have noticed that you can't use password authentication on a push from the terminal any longer so I have created a general token on GitHub. When I try to use it from within VSCode terminal cmd prompt or powershell with the following syntax I get a popup demanding username and password, but neither GitHub user name with password or token works. I can push using the GitHub desktop app using my GitHub username and token, but I want to be able to schedule the push inside a .bat file. Here is the format of the push command I have been trying to use from windows cmd or powershell.

`git push https:/<mytoken@github.com>/<myusername>/TEST.git`

Is there a better way to do this?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

First create a *Personal access token*: https://github.com/settings/tokens

Then push changes as follows:

```
git push https://username:TOKEN@github.com/username/TEST.git branch
```